# How to find one entry in Bash history

Tags: bash

When I open bash and press the up arrow I see the last command I have typed. Continues presses of the up arrow will show a series of commands typed on the past.

How do I find one specific command from that list, instead of having to press the up arrow n times?

Comment: Try this https://lifehacker.com/ctrl-r-to-search-and-other-terminal-history-tricks-278888

Comment: As you are mentioning needing to press `UpArrow` a specific number of times, do you know that the command is `n` command back in the history?

Comment: Using the history command is out of question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Press `CTRL+R` and start typing. Press `CTRL+R` again to get the next found.

Answer (score 2):

You can use below command to find in .bash_history file

```
sed -n '/commandwhichyouwanttosearch/p' bash.history
```

example

Suppose if you want to search for ls command in .bash_history

```
history | sed -n '/ls/p'
```

Answer (score 2):

This one has not yet been mentioned.

```
!start-of-command
```

e.g.

```
echo hello
ls
!echo
#finds echo hello
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of pressing <kbd>UpArrow</kbd> exactly `n` times, you would use

```
!-n
```

in the shell.

This would invoke the history expansion facility of the `bash` shell and would replace the expansion with the command `n` steps back in history (and execute it).

Example:

```
$ history
    1  ls
    2  ls
    3  ls
    4  history
    5  echo hello
    6  echo good night
    7  history
$ !-3
echo hello
hello
```

See the "HISTORY EXPANSION" section in the `bash` manual.

Answer (score 1):

### history + grep (or any other text searching command)

If you want to list all history entries containing string "foo":
 `history | grep "foo"`

`history` - shows all commands in the history buffer

`grep "foo"` - searches for lines containing the string `foo`, and you can also use regular expressions accordingly to manual of grep.

---

### Reverse i-search

If you want to go back through history (like you did before with arrow keys) using ctrl+r is the way to go. Just press ctrl+r and start typing. You can press ctrl+r multiple times when the phrase is already typed and it will iterate back through matching history entries

---

### Fuzzy Finder

This is my personal preference. Its solution is not vanilla out of the box, but I think it deserves some credit. You can install a fuzzy finder extension for bash and it will make searching for many things much more efficient (it replaces reverse i-search so ctrl+r is being used as a shortcut for searching in history).